# VideoPlayer not contain player or url proberty unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, video, playback

VideoPlayer unity not contain player or url proberty what shall i do please?

i tried alot and not successful

Library

```cs
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Video;



public class vid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VideoClip videoClip; // Make sure to assign the VideoClip in the Inspector

    private VideoPlayer player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();

        if (videoClip != null)
        {
            player.clip = videoClip;
            player.Play();
            
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("No VideoClip is assigned. Please assign a VideoClip in the Inspector.");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: well mine has the option to change from video clip to URL on it.  havent tried plugging in a web url, but it would also apply to file urls - so you could download the file and plug it in

Comment: It has url property check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html)